# What could cause SHGetFolderLocation to return false with Lasterror set to 59?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have an application that sometimes fails to obtain the path for the `AppData` folder.

The situation seems only to occur on our Citrix server farm and not for every user and not all the time (I was pretty much unable to reproduce it).

The problem manifests in the following way:

`SHGetFolderLocation` is called that way:

```
 Value := SHGetFolderLocation (0, CLSID, 0, 0, pidl);
 try
   case Value of
     S_OK:
     begin
       if not ShGetPathfromIDList(pidl, Path) then
         RaiseLastOSError();
       Result := trim(string(Path));
       break;
     end;
   else
     RaiseLastOSError();
   end;
 finally
   CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
 end;
```

(`CLSID` is set to `CSIDL_APPDATA` which is defined as `0x001a`)

What we see, according to the stack trace, is that `SHGetFolderLocation` returns false, triggering a call to `RaiseLastOSError` which indicates that last error code was 59:

```
System Error. Code: 59. An unexpected network error occurred
```

I'm scratching by head trying to find out how I could receive such an error message: even if there was a network issue, I can't see any reason for `SHGetFolderLocation` to be affected by it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you think SHGetFolderLocation has effect on GetLastError result? You already have correct error code in Value, just call OleCheck(Value) instead of RaiseLastOSError.

Comment: Good question, thank you. I will modify the code and see what I get instead.

Comment: Don`t forget that OleCheck will not raise an exception if Value is equal to S_FALSE. Maybe it is better to use OleError instead of OleCheck.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov `SHGetFolderLocation()` doesn't return `S_FALSE`. And the reason `OleCheck()` does not raise on `S_FALSE` is because it is not an error condition, it is a success condition.

Comment: Looks like Folder Redirections are used on the Citrix environment and perhaps sometimes the redirected location is unavailable or too busy? (e.g. redirecting AppData to a fileserver is like a dos attack on the fileserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHGetFolderLocation()` and `SHGetPathfromIDList()` do not report error codes via `GetLastError()`, so you cannot use `RaiseLastOSError()` in this situation.

`SHGetFolderLocation()` returns an `HRESULT` value.  You can pass that value to the RTL's `OleCheck()` function, which will raise an exception if the `HRESULT` value represents an error.

Unfortunately, `SHGetPathfromIDList()` does not report error codes at all, so if you want to raise an exception if it fails, you have to raise your own exception manually.

You should not call `CoTaskMemFree()` unless `SHGetFolderLocation()` returns `S_OK`, as that is the only condition where your `pidl` is updated to point at allocated memory. Any other return value will set your `pidl` pointer to `nil` instead.

Try this:

```pascal
OleCheck(SHGetFolderLocation(0, CLSID, 0, 0, pidl));
try
  if not SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, Path) then
    raise Exception.Create('Cannot get filesystem path from PIDL');
  Result := string(Path);
finally
  CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
end;
```

Which can be greatly simplified by just using `SHGetFolderPath()` instead:

```pascal
OleCheck(SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, Path));
```

Comment: "DO NOT call CoTaskMemFree() if SHGetFolderLocation() returns anything other than S_OK, as that is the only condition where the pidl pointer has a meaningful value." that is actually wrong: the documentation states "The ppidl parameter is set to NULL on failure" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderlocation)

Comment: @Stephane thanks, I have updated the wording of that statement